# PL/SQL Concatenation

Tags: oracle, plsql, concatenation, execute-immediate

i have a procedure that have in entry two parameters 
CREATE_PARTITION( yearSource IN VARCHAR2 , yearDestination IN VARCHAR2 )

when i want to insert the yearSource concatenated with another string , nothing is inserted in the table

i declare the variable yearAA which take the yearSource and i concatenate it with a 'AA'

**yearAA varchar2(30) := yearSource||'AA';**

to insert it i use :

**execute immediate ' INSERT INTO MOUADTEST2018 VALUES('||yearAA||')';**

result : Nothing inserted 
and it shows this message  **ORA-00984: column not allowed here**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to quote the value. As it is, if `yearAA` is `2018AA`, your code gets interpreted as:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO MOUADTEST2018 VALUES(2018AA)';
```

Which tries to run

```
INSERT INTO MOUADTEST2018 VALUES(2018AA)
```

Which throws an error because `2018AA` isn't in quotes, so Oracle thinks it must be an identifier (like a column name).

You could change your code to

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO MOUADTEST2018 VALUES('''||yearAA||''')';
```

But this isn't a best practice, since it allows SQL injection. Instead, use bind variables.

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO MOUADTEST2018 VALUES(:1)' using yearAA;
```

Also, I don't think you need `execute immediate`, so you can just do:

```
insert into MOUADTEST2018 values(yearAA);
```